# Accessing Word's nested tables in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have a word document which has some tables , in which each table has other nested table.

I am trying to fill these tables from VB.Net code...actually what happens is that the VB.Net  does not access the nested tables.

I even tried to iterate through cells and find out if the cell does contain a table ..but still did not work...

appreciate if anyone can give an idea

Comment: I don't see a single piece of code. We are not able to help you if you don't show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick to finding out whether a cell contains one or more nested tables is to query `Cell.Tables.Count`. If the value returned is greater than zero, there are nested tables.

Since you provide no code as a starting point, the following sample is generic and can be adapted to any situation. It loops all cells in a table, including all those in nested tables. It can be used in VB.NET or VBA: The two lines that are different for VBA are commented out, just above the VB.NET lines. For VB.NET it assumes there's a class-level field named `wdApp` that represents the `Word.Application` and that the namespace `System.Diagnotics` is imported.

(Note: the same approach works in C#, as well, just a slightly different syntax.)

```
Sub LoopAllCellsIncludingNestedTables()
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim tbl As word.Table

    counter = 0
    'Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    tbl = wdApp.ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    counter = LoopCells(counter, tbl)
    Debug.Print counter
End Sub

Function LoopCells(counter As Long, tbl As word.Table) As Long
    Dim cel As word.Cell
    Dim nestedTbl As word.Table

    For Each cel In tbl.Range.Cells
        counter = counter + 1
        If cel.Tables.Count > 0 Then
            For Each nestedTbl In cel.Tables
                counter = LoopCells(counter, nestedTbl)
            Next
        End If
    Next
    'LoopCells = counter
    Return counter
End Function
```